# How to keep an accurate cache using redis of ruby models/attributes/methods using sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, caching, sidekiq

I'm using sidekiq for concurrency and redis for caching my most-used models, attributes, and methods.

I feel that I will be running into race conditions, and my cached data getting out of sync frequently.

What is a good pattern/strategy to make sure that my redis cache is in sync with my postgres database?

For example, I have Customer and any time the customer gets saved, I also want to store a cached version of the instance in redis. I want to use the cached version always if it exists and if not, cache it.

Comment: Use `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY` to emit and handle cache invalidations